# Reading strings, integers etc from files using fscanf

Tags: c, string, integer, scanf

I'd like your help with understanding how should I do the following:

I have a file that contains integers separated by spaces ' '. I need to read all integers, sort them and write them as a strings to another file. I wrote a code, but I read char by char, put the word in an  char sub_arr [Max_Int] and when I met ' ', I put these chars, now one string, after atoi-ing it into another Main int array,until reaching the end of the file, string by string,  and then I sorted and itoa-ing them and wrote them in another file.

But then I remembered that there's a [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/)  function:I read about it and still I didn't understand completely what does it do and how to use it.

In my case, where all integers separated by space, can I write `fscanf(myFile,"%s",word)`? would it know not to consider ' ' and stop at the end of the specific string?! How?

More than that, Can I write `fscanf(myFile,"%d",number)` and it would give me the next number itself? (I must have misunderstood it. Feels like magic).

Comment: is the number of integers for each line fixed ?

Comment: Is it necessary to use C?  Tools like Python, Perl, Ruby, Awk, etc. do this kind of thing really well.

Comment: @ziu: No, it doesn't, Mark: Yes, I'm learning C :)

Comment: @Numerator:  Then that's an excellent reason to use C  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, `fscanf` can give you the next integer. However, you need to provide it with a pointer. Therefore, you need an `&` behind number:

```
fscanf(myFile, "%d", &number);
```

`*scanf` family of functions also automatically skip whitespace (except when given `%c`, `%[` or `%n`).

Your loop with reading file will eventually look like this:

```
while (you_have_space_in_your_array_or_whatever)
{
    int number;
    if (fscanf(myFile, "%d", &number) != 1)
        break;        // file finished or there was an error
    add_to_your_array(number);
}
```

---

Side note: you may think of writing like this:

```
while (!feof(myFile))
{
    int number;
    fscanf(myFile, "%d", &number);
    add_to_your_array(number);
}
```

This, although looks nice, **has a problem**. If you are indeed reaching the end of file, you will have read a garbage number and added to your data before testing the end of file. That is why you should use the `while` loop I mentioned first.

Comment: Thank you @Shahbaz: Yes, I intended to the the second code you wrote since I need to do that until the end of the file, i.e all file contains numbers separated by space. How should I avoid the problem you mentioned?

Comment: @Numerator, by using my first example.

Comment: If it was a binary file, and each 8 bits represented a number, Can I use fscanf in this case as well in some way?

Comment: @Numerator, not in the conventional way. With binary files, [`fread`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) is your friend.

Comment: Detail : "except when given `%c %[] %n`"

Comment: `fscanf(myFile, "%d", &number); if (feof(myFile)) break;` does not check that a successful did indeed occur.  Better to use `if (fscanf(myFile, "%d", &number != 1) break;`

Comment: @chux, you are right. I had improved on these stuff afterwards (trying to write better answers here), but I didn't remember this answer to come back and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

following lines will do your work, following lines will read single integer.

```
int number;
fscanf(myFile, " %d", &number);
```

Put it in a loop until end of file, and place the number in array.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char name[256];
    int age;
    /* create a text file */
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "Josh 25 years old\n");
    fclose(f);

    /* now open it and read it */
    f = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if (fscanf(f, "%s %d", name, &age) !=2)
        ; /* Couln't read name and age */
    printf("Name: %s, Age %d\n", name, age);

}
```

Comment: This has an issue, if for reason the name in the string that is passed to fscanf is bigger than the size of your "char name[256]" you produce a buffer overflow.

Comment: Well, the code *as is* doesn't have an issue, because it specifies the contents of the buffer, and in the code, `strlen(name)` is < 256.  In general, of course, you're right -  `fscanf_s` should be used instead.  But the question was about fscanf usage.