# Finding certain combination in a text file

Tags: c, file, combinations

I have a text file of combinations without repetition of 6 number ranging from 1 to 10, like this:

```
2 3 8 9 6 4 
8 3 1 4 7 9 
1 3 5 7 6 9 
1 5 7 9 8 4 
1 3 5 4 8 7 
2 4 6 8 7 1 
6 7 8 3 5 9 
3 1 6 2 7 9 
1 7 4 2 5 8 
3 4 9 2 1 7 
...
```

and I have a gold combination, let's say: 2, 1, 3, 9, 8, 5

I want to check how many times I have a combination in my text file that matches 5 numbers of the gold combination. This is my code attempt:

```
// Including C Standard Libraries
#include <stdint.h>

#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<time.h> 

int main()
{

    // Gold Combination
    int n1 = 2;
    int n2 = 1;
    int n3 = 3;
    int n4 = 9;
    int n5 = 8;
    int n6 = 5;

    // Numbers of Matching Combinations
    int match_comb = 0; 

    // Creating a file to see combinations content
    char ch, file_name[25];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("combinations.txt", "r");  // Read Mode

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int j = 0;
    int mn = 0;  // Number of matched numbers
    int x[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

    char c;

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\n')
        {

        }
        else
        {

            x[j] = c;


            if (j == 5)
            {
                if(x[0]==n1 || x[0]==n2 || x[0]==n3 || x[0]==n5 || x[0]==n6){
                    mn += 1;
                }if(x[1]==n1 || x[1]==n2 || x[1]==n3 || x[1]==n5 || x[1]==n6){
                    mn += 1;
                }if(x[2]==n1 || x[2]==n2 || x[2]==n3 || x[2]==n5 || x[2]==n6){
                    mn += 1;
                }if(x[3]==n1 || x[3]==n2 || x[3]==n3 || x[3]==n5 || x[3]==n6){
                    mn += 1;
                }if(x[4]==n1 || x[4]==n2 || x[4]==n3 || x[4]==n5 || x[4]==n6){
                    mn += 1;
                }if(x[5]==n1 || x[5]==n2 || x[5]==n3 || x[5]==n5 || x[5]==n6){
                    mn += 1;
                }

                if ( mn == 5)
                {
                    match_comb += 1;  // Adding One the the Match Combinantions counter
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)  // Resetting x array
                {
                    x[i] = 0;
                }    

                mn = 0;  // Resetting
                j = -1;  // Resetting j

            }

            j += 1;


        }
    }


    printf("Number of Matching Combinations:");
    printf("%d", match_comb);
    printf("\n");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

But, I think the code is not working, because it always says that there are 0 matched combinations .. Are there ways to simplify or make my code work?

also, this only works for the case of numbers with one digit, but in the case I have bigger range, let's say 1-20, I am not really sure how to gather the numbers from the text file .. I was thinking in a condition where there was a counter  after every space, if the counter is one, take the character as a number of one digit, if the counter is two, gather the two characters and do something to tell the code to gather the two characters and use the resulted number, but I don't know how to do that ..

Edit:

```
int main()
{

    // Gold Combination
    int n1 = 20;
    int n2 = 1;
    int n3 = 35;
    int n4 = 9;
    int n5 = 18;
    int n6 = 5;

    // Numbers of Matching Combinations
    int match_comb = 0; 

    // Creating a file to see combinations content
    char ch, file_name[25];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("combinations.txt", "r");  // Read Mode

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int j = 0;
    int mn = 0;  // Number of matched numbers
    int x[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

    int c;

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {

        //x[j] = fscanf(fp, "%d", &c);

        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &x[0], &x[1], &x[2], &x[3], &x[4], &x[5]);

        printf("%d", x[0]);
        printf(" ");
        printf("%d", x[1]);
        printf(" ");
        printf("%d", x[2]);
        printf(" ");
        printf("%d", x[3]);
        printf(" ");
        printf("%d", x[4]);
        printf(" ");
        printf("%d", x[5]);

        if(x[0]==n1 || x[0]==n2 || x[0]==n3 || x[0]==n5 || x[0]==n6){
            mn += 1;
        }if(x[1]==n1 || x[1]==n2 || x[1]==n3 || x[1]==n5 || x[1]==n6){
            mn += 1;
        }if(x[2]==n1 || x[2]==n2 || x[2]==n3 || x[2]==n5 || x[2]==n6){
            mn += 1;
        }if(x[3]==n1 || x[3]==n2 || x[3]==n3 || x[3]==n5 || x[3]==n6){
            mn += 1;
        }if(x[4]==n1 || x[4]==n2 || x[4]==n3 || x[4]==n5 || x[4]==n6){
            mn += 1;
        }if(x[5]==n1 || x[5]==n2 || x[5]==n3 || x[5]==n5 || x[5]==n6){
            mn += 1;
        }

        if ( mn == 5)
        {
            match_comb += 1;  // Adding One the the Match Combinantions counter
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)  // Resetting x array
        {
            x[i] = 0;
        }    

        mn = 0;  // Resetting

        printf("\n");


    }

    printf("Number of Matching Combinations:");
    printf("%d", match_comb);
    printf("\n");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unusual to include "\n" in the string passed to `perror`.  And it's very useful to include the path used in the error message. IOW, use `perror("combinations.txt")`

Comment: If your input is text and the first character of the file is `2`, then you should not expect it to match the integer 2. You need to conver the text input to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with:

```
x[j] = c;
```

This assigns a char to an integer. You need to convert c to an integer. For example by subtracting the character code of zero:

```
x[j] = c-'0';
```

You can use `isdigit(c)` to check whether `c` is really a digit.

Either with the help of the debugger or by using `printf` to show the exact values of the `x[0], x[1], ...` you get a clearer view of what was going wrong.

As for reading numbers of more than 1 digit, the best idea is to use a function such as `fscanf(fp, "%d", &c)` which automatically converts the read characters to a number. Note that if you use `&c` here, `c` needs to be an int, not a char.

If you want to work with `fscanf`, you need to remove the calls to `fgetc` (in your while-loop), because otherwise `fgetc` everytime removes a character. Removing a character is no problem when that's a space or a newline, but it is a problem for the first digit in the line. When `fgetc` can not be used anymore for checking end-of-file, use the return value of `fscanf` as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543341/reading-strings-integers-etc-from-files-using-fscanf/11543672#11543672). For example:

```
while (true)  // endless loop, but will end via a 'break'
{
    //  remove if(c == ' ' || c == '\n')
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &c) != 1)  // check whether fscanf found 1 input
        break; // this jumps out of the while loop
    ....  // rest of your code
}
```

If you really want to use `fgetc` for reading the numbers, you need something like:

```
if (isdigit(c))
    num = num * 10 + (c - '0');
```

and not yet putting `num` in the X-array until you encounter a non-digit. `num` needs to be reset to 0 thereafter.

As for the code you use for calculating the number of matches, it looks quite clever if you're fully new to programming. An improvement would be to also put the `n` values in an array and to use for-loops to check the number of matches.

Comment: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char*’ [-Wformat=]
             x[j] = scanf("%d", &c);

Comment: @Delfin yes, you're right. `c` needs to be an int in that case.

Comment: but if c is int, how do I know when I have a newline character '\n' ?

Comment: @Delfin scanf("%d") automatically skips newlines and spaces.

Comment: @Delfin If you look up scanf in the documentation, you get a better grip on how it works and what the different options are.

Comment: @Delfin About scanf, if you need reading from a file, you need to use fscanf(fp, "%d", &c).  I will update the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543672/12046409 has a discussion about using fscanf to read integers

Comment: Well .. I think now my code is working, but I have a new question, Why fscanf does not select the first number? it skips the very first one

Comment: Well, now it works .. But now, when I do this:       if(x[0]==n1 || x[0]==n2 || x[0]==n3 || x[0]==n5 || x[0]==n6){
            mn += 1;
        }    ... Why it doesn't detect when x[0] = 9 ?

Comment: @Delfin print out the values of x[0], x[1], ... to check what they really are.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing, that is how I know my if statement doesn't detect 9 Edit.. Oh I am an idiot, solved, thanks